# Parse tags inside XML with XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a xml like this:

```
<node>
    <par>
        Lorem ipsum dolor <bold>sit</bold> amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    <par>
</node>
```

I have to print a html like this:

```
<p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
    <span class="bolder">sit</span>
    <span>amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</p>
```

I cannot find a way to truncate the text by the middle `bold` tag and add a new tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following transformation, when applied to the input you provided, produces the result you requested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates /></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par/text()">
        <span><xsl:copy-of select="." /></span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bold">
        <span class="bolder"><xsl:value-of select="." /></span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="par">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <span>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bold/text()">
    <span class="bolder">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to this input XML:

```
<node>
  <par>
    Lorem ipsum dolor <bold>sit</bold> amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </par>
</node>
```

produces the following output:

```
<p>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
  <span class="bolder">sit</span>
  <span>amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Just saw @hielsnoppe beat me to it with essentially the same solution, so I would suggest you accept their answer.

Comment: @Pablo Depends on whether you need space normalization. If yes, this is the better one. @ BenL Fair play, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by using the `text()` selector and indexing it either side of the internal element. Therefore the selector for `'Lorem ipsum dolor'` when in context of `par` would be `text()[1]` and `'amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'` would be `text()[2]`

Comment: In that way Iḿ loosing the `sit`, that should be in the span with the special class.
Can I some how, convert the `<bold>` tag into string? and parse it?

Comment: You can still select sit with `par/bold`